# All my references to the stage method are throwing null reference errors in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, reference, stage

I'm not sure what the change was that caused this, but suddenly i'm getting null object references in all the cases that I use the stage method as a parameter. My code is too long to fit all the different instances, so I'll just attach one or two.

```
package com.Mass.basics1
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;


public class Main extends MovieClip
{


public var ourPlanet:Cosmo = new Cosmo(stage);
public var ourAsteroid:Asteroid = new Asteroid();
private var numStars:int = 80;
private var numAsteroids:int = 5;
public static var a:Number = 0;
private var stageRef:Stage;
//public var ourAsteroid:Asteroid = new Asteroid(stage);
//private var ourAsteroid:Asteroid = new Asteroid();


//our constructor function. This runs when an object of 
//the class is created
public function Main()
{

    //create an object of our ship from the Ship class

    stop();

    //add it to the display list
    stage.addChild(ourPlanet);

    ourPlanet.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
    ourPlanet.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
    this.stageRef = stageRef;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < numStars; i++)
    {
        stage.addChildAt(new Star(stage), stage.getChildIndex(ourPlanet));
    }


    for (var o:int = 0; o < numAsteroids; o++)
    {
        stage.addChildAt(new Asteroid(),    stage.getChildIndex(ourPlanet));
    }
```

My debugger tells me there is a null object reference at line 13, and this code is from my engine. Cosmo is another external file that is linked to a symbol. I'll post the code from there, but there are about 4 of these errors across 4 different .as files, but it'd be too much code to put in here, so I'll just add from one other file I think would be important.

Code From Cosmo.as

```
package com.Mass.basics1
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import com.senocular.utils.KeyObject;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class Cosmo extends MovieClip
{


private var stageRef:Stage;
private var key:KeyObject;
private var speed:Number = 20;
private var vx:Number = 0;
private var vy:Number = 0;
private var friction:Number = 0.93;
private var maxspeed:Number = 8;
public var destroyed:Boolean = false;
public function Cosmo(stageRef:Stage)
{
    this.stageRef = stageRef;
    var key:KeyObject = new KeyObject(stage);

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
}



public function loop(e:Event) : void
{
    //keypresses
    if (key.isDown(Keyboard.A))
        vx -= speed;
    else if (key.isDown(Keyboard.D))
        vx += speed;
    else
        vx *= friction;

    if (key.isDown(Keyboard.W))
        vy -= speed;
    else if (key.isDown(Keyboard.S))
        vy += speed;
    else
        vy *= friction;

    //update position   
    x += vx;
    y += vy;

    //speed adjustment
    if (vx > maxspeed)
        vx = maxspeed;
    else if (vx < -maxspeed)
        vx = -maxspeed;

    if (vy > maxspeed)
        vy = maxspeed;
    else if (vy < -maxspeed)
        vy = -maxspeed;

    //ship appearance
    rotation = vx;
    scaleX = (maxspeed - Math.abs(vx))/(maxspeed* 4) + 0.75;

    //stay inside screen
    if (x > stageRef.stageWidth) 
    {
        x = stageRef.stageWidth;
        vx = -vx;
    }
    else if (x < 0) 
    {
        x = 0;
        vx = -vx;
    }

    if (y > stageRef.stageHeight)
    {
        y = stageRef.stageHeight;
        vy = -vy;
    }
    else if (y < 0) 
    {
        y = 0;
        vy = -vy;
    }


}

} 

}
```

I'm also getting an error here at line 26 for the same thing.

Code from another file

```
package com.senocular.utils {

import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.utils.Proxy;
import flash.utils.flash_proxy;
```

/**
    * The KeyObject class recreates functionality of
    * Key.isDown of ActionScript 1 and 2
    *
    * Usage:
    * var key:KeyObject = new KeyObject(stage);
    * if (key.isDown(key.LEFT)) { ... }
    */
    dynamic public class KeyObject extends Proxy {

```
private static var stage:Stage;
private static var keysDown:Object;

public function KeyObject(stage:Stage) {
    construct(stage);
}

public function construct(stage:Stage):void {
    KeyObject.stage = stage;
    keysDown = new Object();
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
}

flash_proxy override function getProperty(name:*):* {
    return (name in Keyboard) ? Keyboard[name] : -1;
}

public function isDown(keyCode:uint):Boolean {
    return Boolean(keyCode in keysDown);
}

public function deconstruct():void {
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
    keysDown = new Object();
    KeyObject.stage = null;
}

private function keyPressed(evt:KeyboardEvent):void {
    keysDown[evt.keyCode] = true;
}

private function keyReleased(evt:KeyboardEvent):void {
    delete keysDown[evt.keyCode];
}
}
}
```

In this file, i'm getting errors at lines 23 and 29. Thanks in advance, let me know if you need more information of any kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stage property is going to be null until added to the display list hierarchy of the stage. You can't add the object to the stage until after the constructor is executed, so therefore you won't ever be able to access stage in the constructor. It's going to be null.

Call the construct method after creating the instance and adding it to the stage's display list hierarchy.